# Where is the configuration file for application in Tibco administrator (version 5.3)

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I want to find the configuration file for application configurations in Tibco administrator. Then I can know all runtime configurations of my application.

[image]

I tried to findout in the path /opt/sw/tibco/tra/domain/SOADEV/datafiles/[my app]_root but this configuration is out of date, and is not latest configuration.

Here is example:

The configuration file contains "ExchangeRate" item

[image]

Tibco Admin doesn't display ExchangeRate item (in path Global/Vn)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**tibco/tra/domain/[ENV_NAME]/datafiles/[my app]_root** is actually right place where all Global variables values and package code are stored after package deployment.

I am guessing you are looking to the wrong package or something wrong with the deployment.
All global variables should be stored in

```
[my app]_root\defaultVars\defaultVars.substvar
```

or subfolders

```
[my app]_root\defaultVars\[folder_name]\defaultVars.substvar
```

the variable can be deployment settable and service settable. Please see more details here https://community.tibco.com/questions/difference-between-global-variables-earservice-and-service-instance-levels

Also there are several ways global variables can be overridden. Please see https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-47854

> 1). In Designer -> Global Variables panel, click the pencil icon (Open
> Advanced Editor) at top right, select the global variable and right
> click ->  “Override Variable”.
>
> 2). Use the Project -> “Save as” option to save as a new project.
> Global variables will then be editable.
>
> 3). Go to Tester -> "Advanced" test settings with the "-p
> PATH/properties.cfg" argument, with PATH being the absolute path and
> properties the file that override global variables.
>
> 4).Change the variable in TIBCO administrator GUI during deployment.
>
> 5). Manually edit the bwengine.tra.

Comment: thanks @David, I checked global variables in your paths. I see that they include many variables that doesn't show on Tibco admin, although they have property: <deploymentSettable>true</deploymentSettable>
How can I know what are variables will show on Tibco admin ?

Comment: @tabic GV with <deploymentSettable>true</deploymentSettable>  should be available in tibco admin.  Just try to undeploy package. check that nothing is in tibco/tra/domain/[ENV_NAME]/datafiles/[my app]_root and deploy again.

Comment: When I undeploy then there is no [my app]_root folder. After that, I deploy again, the folder is available, but it still contains many variables that disappear on Tibco admin

Comment: @tabic can you post example global variable that is missing and also how this variable defined in the source code ? You can rename to some random value.

Comment: Also there are several ways global variables can be overridden. Please see https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-47854

Comment: I posted an example in my question. Please see above. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that configuration not overridden in properties.cfg and bwengine.tra ?

Comment: not clear from the example if you have missing GV in source code. for me it looks like you have multiple servers for DEV/PROD environments and some of the GV configuration defined on properties file on server level. something like https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-33614 or may be set as command line https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-23290  you should see the configuration in  bwengine.tra

Comment: I checked the bwengine.tra file, but no overridden found. I can't find the file properties.cfg in my tibco folder

Comment: I updated my pictures in the question to clarify